# How to write rest api method for function update?

Tags: php, mysql

I designed a query to do "Rest api" between C # and MySQL, which is the following function:

```
 function index ()
    {
    $ hadi = "SELECT
      wp_postmeta1.post_id,
      wp_postmeta1.meta_key,
      wp_postmeta1.meta_value
    FROM wp_postmeta1
    WHERE wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku'
    OR wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_stock'
    OR wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_price'
    ORDER BY wp_postmeta1.post_id
    ";
        $ res = query ($ hadi);
    while ($ row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($ res))
    $ rows [] = $ row;
    return $ rows;
    }
```

To test this message:

> http://www.kodakamoz.com/stud.php?method=index

Index Test: Indicates an acceptable display

```
[{"post_id": "1927", "meta_key": "_ stock", "meta_value": "27"}, {"post_id": "1927", "meta_key": "_ price", "meta_value": "15000 "}, {" post_id ":" 1927 "," meta_key ":" _ sku "," meta_value ":" 00302016 "}, {" post_id ":" 1928 "," meta_key ":" _ price "," meta_value ": "2200"}, {"post_id": "1928", "meta_key": "_ stock", "meta_value": "10"}, {"post_id": "1928", "meta_key": "_ sku", "meta_value" ":" 00301421 "}, {" post_id ":" 1929 "," meta_key ":" _ sku "," meta_value ":" 00301056 "}, {" post_id ":" 1929 "," meta_key ":" _ price ", "meta_value": "5500"}, {"post_id": "1929", "meta_key": "_ stock", "meta_value": "10"},
```

and also

```
function edit ($ post_id)
{
    $ res = query ("SELECT
  wp_postmeta1.post_id,
  wp_postmeta1.meta_key,
  wp_postmeta1.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta1
WHERE wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku'
OR wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_stock'
OR wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_price'
HAVING `post_id` = $ post_id
ORDER BY wp_postmeta1.post_id ");
$ rows = [];
while ($ row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($ res))
$ rows [] = $ row;
return $ rows;
}
```

To test this message:

> http://www.kodakamoz.com/stud.php?method=edit&post_id=1928

Edit Test: Displays an acceptable display

```
[{"post_id": "1928", "meta_key": "_ price", "meta_value": "2200"}, {"post_id": "1928", "meta_key": "_ stock", "meta_value": "10 "}, {" post_id ":" 1928 "," meta_key ":" _ sku "," meta_value ":" 00301421 "}]
```

Now for function update I wrote this method which is error

```
function update ()
{
    $ post_id = $ _ GET ['post_id'];
$ meta_key = $ _GET ['meta_key'];
$ meta_value = $ _GET ['meta_value'];

    $ res = query ("UPDATE` wp_postmeta1`
SET `meta_value` = $ meta_value
WHERE `wp_postmeta1`.`post_id` = $ post_id
AND `wp_postmeta1`.`meta_key` = '_stock'
AND `wp_postmeta1`.`meta_value` =` meta_value`
LIMIT 1 ");
  if ($ res)
    return "1 record updated";
else return "error";
}
```

To test this message:

> http://www.kodakamoz.com/stud.php?method=update&post_id=1928

update test: error
What is your way

Comment: I'm confused.  You tagged your question with C#, but the code looks very much like PHP.  Which language are you using?  In any case, you should read up on using prepared statements with MySQL.

Comment: I'm going to do between C # Sharp and MySQL rest api
But now I'm doing php programming

Answer (score -2):

Just yesterday I learned about something called "Primitive Obession". That it can be beneficial to use pretty [flat classes for ID's, primary keys and other important values to avoid mixups](https://andrewlock.net/using-strongly-typed-entity-ids-to-avoid-primitive-obsession-part-1/). Particular WebService Calls might benefit from it, due to the weak Typisation inherent in the Web Part.

Another thing I usually do is concurrency control. I prefer Optimistic Concurrency (do not lock, just test for changes during update). In SQL I got the Rowversion column to avoid Update Race Conditions. I just retreive it with all the rest and it is a thing to add to the Updates where clause. Maybe throw an SQL Exception if there is a missmatch.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33225308/3346583), timestamp can be used similary to rowversion with the right switches. Do keep in mind that a exceptionally fast query and update (an automatic process) can still run into/cause a timestamp colission. There was wisdom in having SQL rowversion be a simple running counter.

Comment: What is your solution?
What query to write

Comment: @HadiFazilat I am a bit to rusty in PHP to write a Query for it. IIRC, it used those wierd prepared statements rather then parametized queries. I honestly only saw this question because of the C# tag.